# About "living as they do"

Tags: grammar

> Living as they **do** in a different world from adults, children have
>   problems peculiar to themselves.

1. Is "do" the same as "live"?
2. Isn't "do" ungrammatical to use there, because "living" is a present participle? 
   So, I think that "are" is grammatical as in *"Living as they **are** in a different world from adults, children have problems peculiar to themselves."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's fine.

Per [Merriam-Webster's](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/do) eighth sense of its intransitive definition:

> **8** —used as a substitute verb to avoid repetition
>   // wanted to run and play as children *do*
>   —used especially in British English following a modal auxiliary or perfective *have*
>   // a great many people had died, or would *do*
>   — Bruce Chatwin

In this case, as you say, it's effectively bypassing the repetition of *live*:

> Living as they *live* in a different world from adults, children have problems particular to themselves.

But *living as they live* (or the repetition of any verb) is a construction that isn't normally used. Using *do* in these cases is both grammatical and more common than verb repetition.

---

Interestingly, unlike in the case of using *do*, if the verb is repeated, I'm more comfortable with adding another comma directly after it.

So:

> Living as they do in a different world from adults, children have problems particular to themselves.
>
> Living as they live***,*** in a different world from adults, children have problems particular to themselves.

But this is a minor stylistic point, and the comma is optional in both cases. (Depending on the nuance of what is being expressed.)